# Не работает функция .toggleClass

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть ссылка `a(href= "javascript://0" onclick = "hidden ()")` , и сама функция

```
function hidden () {
   $('.site-nav__menu-item--hidden').toggleClass('.site-nav__menu-item--visible');
};
```

Есть объект, умеющий менять свои свойства по нажатию на эту ссылку (путем добавления/удаления нового класса, который умеет перекрывать эти свойства)

```
.site-nav__menu-item--hidden{
    display: none;
}
.site-nav__menu-item--visible{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Почему не работает скрипт?

Comment: toggleClass уже знает, что вы добавляете или удаляете класс, соответственно "." ставить не нужно. В вашем примере добавляется класс ".site-nav__menu-item--visible", а вам нужен "site-nav__menu-item--visible". Вообщем точку уберите.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

```js
function hide() {
  $('.block').toggleClass('site-nav__menu-item--visible site-nav__menu-item--hidden');
};
```

```css
.site-nav__menu-item--hidden{
    display: none;
}
.site-nav__menu-item--visible{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block site-nav__menu-item--hidden">Block</div>

<button id="toggleBlock" onclick="hide()">click</button>
```